# Add PK on a subclass (inheritance) different from parent class ID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

These days I have been working on the Inheritance with Entity Framwork 6(MVC, VisualStudio 2015, code-first). Trying different aspects, I found the need of generate a PrimaryKey that identifies the Subclass, separate of the primaryKey/ForeignKey that inherits from the parent class.
The idea that i want to develop is this one:

```
public class Person
{

    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

}

public class Student : Person
{

    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

}
```

I have been seraching for other people that tried this but I didn't find anything. I'm not sure if its possible to do or not this so if anyone can help me I will appreciate it a lot

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure you can with just data annotations, however.... why do you even want to do this? Having a consistent name for your PK is quite useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would describe a `Student`, and you would have to describe the meaning of `Student.StudentId` and `Student.PersonId`, could you give a proper description?

It seems to me that the only reason you want to give a Student a new property for the primary key because of the Identifier of this property, not because of a real proper meaning.

The method you should use when modelling inheritance in Entity Framework, depends on the type of queries you will most often use.

Suppose you have three types of Persons: Students, Teachers and Parents. Consider which type of queries you will most often do:

1. Will you most often ask for Students who have ..., or Parents that ...
2. Or will you most often as for Persons that... and seldom for Students who... or Teachers that...

**(1) Mostly ask for Students that...: Use TPC**

If you model your inheritance strategy as [Table per Concrete Class (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines), then Students, Teachers and Parents will each have their own table. There is no common Parents table. All Parent properties that a Student has, are in the Students tables and similar all these Parent properties are also in the Teachers table.

This inheritance strategy is best if you mostly ask for Students who... and seldom for Persons that... Using TPC asking for Students who... will only need one table. Asking for Persons that... will always need the concatenation of the results of queries on Students who... and Teachers that... and Parents who...

I find that this is the inheritance strategy I most often use.

**(2) Mostly ask for Persons who...: Use TPT**

If those are the most used queries, it is best to model all Person data in a separate table and let Students, Teachers and Parents all have some reference to their Person data: [Table-Per-Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

**How to implement TPC**

If you implement inheritance according to TPC, then there will not be a separate Person table. No need to give Persons an Id.

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Student : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Id{get; set;
    ...
}
```

If you plan to never instantiate a Person, only Students, Teachers and Parents, condsder declaring the Person class abstract

By the way, if you give the primary key property the default name `Id`, entity framework will know that this should be your primary key. No need for attributes, nor fluent API.

In your DbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Map(student =>
        {
            student.MapInheritedProperties();
            student.ToTable(nameof(MyDbContext.Students));
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Map(teacher =>
        {
            teacher.MapInheritedProperties();
            teacher.ToTable(nameof(MyDbContext.Teachers));
        });
        // etc. for Parent
    }
}
```

**How to implement TPT**

There will be a Persons table, and Students and Teachers will refer to the Persons table.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    ...
}
class Student
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // A student has Person data via foreign key:
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
    ...        
 }
 class Teacher
 {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // A Teacher has Person data via foreign key:
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
    ...        
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! finally implemented the (2), I find that if u don't declare a PK on the base class then you can define your own PK in the subclass. But you can't do this with TPT you should implement TPH